# Please can ticker overlays be moved to the right?

Tags: feature-request, chat, feed

Ticker overlay feeds are useful for high-volume feeds because they don't get in the way of the conversation so much, but I think they'd do so even less if they were positioned differently:

[image]
[image]

This is especially noticeable if a conversation thread you are trying to follow includes messages at the top of the screen, or if you want to 'scroll to my last message' as the buttons end up covered by the feed.

Please can they be shifted over to the right?